# Update an UITextView size that is set via NSLayout in Swift 3

Tags: swift, uitextview, nslayoutconstraint

I have a variable in my `UIViewController` that is tied to a constraint setting up the `UITextView`'s height:
`var textViewHeight: Int!`

Here is the constraint:
`self.view.addConstraintsWithFormat(format: "V:|-74-[v0(\(textViewHeight!))]", views: self.textView)`

I use this extension:

```
extension UIView
{
    func addConstraintsWithFormat(format: String, views: UIView...)
    {
        var viewDict = [String: AnyObject]()
        for (index, view) in views.enumerated()
        {
            view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
            let key = "v\(index)"
            viewDict[key] = view
        }
        addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraints(withVisualFormat: format, options: NSLayoutFormatOptions(), metrics: nil, views: viewDict))
    }
}
```

I have set up a Notification that triggers when the keyboard shows up.
It is triggered correctly (I have a `print` and it always fires correctly) and the function that is executed includes this code:

```
if let keyboardSize = sender.userInfo?[UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey] as? CGRect {
        print(keyboardSize.height)
        self.textViewHeight = Int(self.view.frame.height-keyboardSize.height-100)
        self.view.updateConstraints()
}
```

The keyboard's height is printed correctly but the text view's height is not changed.....
Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply setting the constraints once with visual format will not update the constraints later if the variable value (in this case `textViewHeight`) changes later. So, you'd have to actually set up a constraint via code that can be modified later as the `textViewHeight` value changes.

Here are the changes you'd need:

1: Add a variable to hold a reference to the constraint you'll want to modify later.

```
var heightConstraint:NSLayoutConstraint!
```

2: Create the constraints for your text view individually instead of using the visual format (`self.view.addConstraintsWithFormat(format: "V:|-74-[v0(\(textViewHeight!))]", views: self.textView)`)

```
// Add vertical constraints individually
let top = NSLayoutConstraint(item:textView, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.top, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.equal, toItem:topLayoutGuide, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.bottom, multiplier:1.0, constant:74.0)
heightConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item:textView, attribute:NSLayoutAttribute.height, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.equal, toItem:nil, attribute:NSLayoutAttribute.notAnAttribute, multiplier:1.0, constant:textViewHeight)
view.addConstraint(top)
view.addConstraint(heightConstraint)
```

3: You are probably better off changing `textViewHeight` to `CGFloat` since all the values you'll deal with there would be `CGFloat` values rather than `Int`.

4: Where you get the keyboard notification, after you calculate `textViewHeight`, add the following line:

```
self.heightConstraint.constant = textViewHeight
```

And that should do the trick since now, when `textViewHeight` changes, the constraint will be updated as well :)

Comment: I tried with `self.view.setNeedsUpdateConstraints()` and it still does nothing :/

Comment: If you can provide a link to the project, I can check to see what is going on by actually running the code, but otherwise, nothing leaps out at me immediately, sorry :(

Comment: The project is quite big and I don't want to put it online for different reasons... So no clue why this doesn't work?

Comment: I can make guesses, but they'd just be guesses - and I hate doing that :) The thing to check would be what the specified height for the text view is and what the current height is at the point where you call `setNeedsUpdateConstraints`. If that doesn't help, then see if you can extract just that view controller into a test project and see if that still displays the same behaviour. Sometimes the process of simplifying shows you what is wrong. If not, you have a sample project you can share to get feedback ...

Comment: Alright, I will do that and ask you again if I didn't solve it :)

Comment: Sure thing :) Just ping me here and I'll take a look if you are still stuck.

Comment: I didn't solve it - should I just upload it as a zip on my github or so?

Comment: Github is fine - if you don't mind that. Or, simply upload the ZIP somewhere and send me the link.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/138690/discussion-between-unixb0y-and-fahim).